# Information about packers

Tags: disassembly, assembly, malware, winapi, packers

i was trying to search for some information about packers just to learn more about it, there is a lot of stuff out there but its hard to find something that really explain that good and clear,
I would love if someone here could share some good materials about that topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, this article from Trustwave does an excellent job covering the topic thoroughly from a beginner's perspective (note: there are formatting errors throughout the article where it mashes two words together every two lines or so, but that aside, the content is good):

https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Basic-Packers--Easy-As-Pie/

Next, combined with the aforementioned article, the Wikipedia page on the topic will help you flesh out the correct terminology to use for your future searches--things like "executable packing," "executable compression," etc.:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression

Those two resources should give you all you need to start building a solid understanding of the topic.